# Set global variable inside `$(document).ready(function()`

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to set a global variable inside `$(document).ready(function()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".editCommentLink").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var window.comment_id = $(e.target).attr("id");
```

It throws error:

```
var window.comment_id = $(e.target).attr("id");
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

When try to place `var comment_id` elsewhere, it constantly report `undefined`

Comment: You cannot declare a variable that's a property of another with `var`. Simply assign to the dot property instead.

Comment: You don't need a declarator if you're assigning a property

Answer (score 1):

Var is not required. Just use `window.global_variable = “your_value”`

For more information about variable scope in javascript  please read following article of MDN [lexical scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 1):

`window.myVar` or `window["myVar"]` is an explicit way to refer to a global variable.

A variable is a global variable if it's declared outside of a function (with or without "var"), or if it's declared inside a function without using "var", or if it's declared as `window.myVar` or `window["myVar"].`

A variable is declared by either assigning a value to it, or by using the keyword var.

One case where it's useful to refer to a global variable as `window.myVar` is if you're inside a function that has a local variable called `myvar.` In that case, `myVar` refers to the local variable, while `window.myVar` refers to the global variable.

`window.variableName` means that the variable is being declared at the global scope. This means any JS code will have access to this variable.

Using `window.` is not necessary but is frequently used as a convention to denote that a variable is global.

Globals are generally to be avoided. You should define variables within the scope of functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should omit the word `var` in `var window.comment_id = ...`.

Comment: but why need to omit?

Comment: you omit 'var' because 'window' already exists.  By adding window.comment_id, you are really just extending window with a new property called comment_id.

Comment: should be in answer

Answer (score 0):

Comments of @ CertainPerformance  and @Li357 perfectly described:

> You cannot declare a variable that's a property of another with var. Simply assign to the dot property instead

you can access `directly` or use `window.Variableanme`

> > > JavaScript has two scopes – global and local. Any variable declared outside of a function belongs to the global scope, and is therefore accessible from anywhere in your code. Each function has its own scope, and any variable declared within that function is only accessible from that function and any nested functions. Because local scope in JavaScript is created by functions, it’s also called function scope. When we put a function inside another function, then we create nested scope.

Comment: down-voter. please put the comments also.It will be helpful